# Should I avoid foreach for ArrayList in Andorid 4.0+?

Tags: android, performance, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I just read this from the book "Android Programming - Pushing the Limits" by Hellman, Erik. Page 38:

```
void loopOne(String[] names) {
    int size = names.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printName(names[i]);
    }
}

void loopTwo(String[] names) {
    for (String name : names) {
        printName(name);
    }
}
void loopThree(Collection<String> names) {
    for (String name : names) {
        printName(name);
    }
}
void loopFour(Collection<String> names) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = names.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        printName(iterator.next());
    }
}
// Avoid using enhanced for-loops for ArrayList 
void loopFive(ArrayList<String> names) {
    int size = names.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printName(names.get(i));
    }
}
```

> These methods show four different ways of looping through collections
>   and arrays. The first two methods have  the same performance, so it’s
>   safe to use the enhanced for-loop on arrays if you’re just going to
>   read the entries.  For Collection objects, you get the same
>   performance when using the enhanced for-loop as when you  manually
>   retrieve an Iterator for traversal. **The only time you should do a
>   manual for-loop is when you have  an ArrayList object.**

I searched before, the foreach and the normal for loop have no performance difference in Java, is there any special reason only for Android (version 4 +)?

Comment: int size = names.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printName(names.get(i));
    }  i think this is the best way to do because list.size() method is not called during looping .... and for each always call .size() ;

Comment: looping is nothing to do with android versions .... i thinks book suggest you to use Loop with better performances

Comment: `for(String name : names){printName(name);}`

Comment: The **fastest** loop is the "**--** counter": `int size = names.size();for(int j = size; j > size ; j--){printName(names.get(j));}`. Cfr.: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/26/performance-comparison-of-different-for-loops-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check info about for loops [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops)

Comment: thank you for your link, this is very helpful for me, because it's an official documentation.
but there is still no explain about why we shouldn't use for ArrayList, ArrayList also implements Iterable...